# Logging in functional programming with Java

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, monads

I am fairly new to Functional Programming and I am trying to use Lambda features in Java to try doing FP. I know Java is not a good choice for learning Functional but in my office I am restricted to use Java and would love to apply some of these principles there.

I created an Optional monad type thing in Java which looks something like this:

```
public abstract class Optional<T> implements Monad<T> {
    //unit function
    public static <T> Optional<T> of(T value) {
        return value != null ? new Present<T>(value) : Absent.<T>instance();
    }

    @Override
    public <V> Monad<V> flatMap(Function<T, Monad<V>> function) {
        return isPresent() ? function.apply(get()) : Absent.<V>instance();
    }
}
```

I am using this for avoiding nested `null` checks in my code, a typical use case where I use this is when I need something like `firstNonNull`.

Use:

```
String value = Optional.<String>of(null)
                .or(Optional.<String>of(null)) //call it some reference
                .or(Optional.of("Hello"))      //other reference
                .flatMap(s -> {
                    return Optional.of(s.toLowerCase());
                })
                .get();
```

This works as a charm. Now the question is that how do I combine logging with this? What if I need to know which of these reference was used? This is useful if there is some semantic attached with those references and I need to log that this reference was not found, trying other option.

Log:

```
some reference is not present and some other business case specific log
```

Is this possible to achieve in Java? I tried to read some possible solutions from web and found `Writer` monad of Haskell, but I got confused and couldn't follow.

**EDIT**

Link to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/NarendraPathai/2a183fe1310df1670486)

Comment: Why did you reinvent Optional? Java 8 already introduced [this class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: @Eran I did this just to learn the basic fundamentals of monadic types. Just for fun.

Comment: So you want to count which reference was used with say a counter?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Maybe I explained it incorrectly, actually what I need to know is which reference was skipped and which was used. For debug level logs.

Comment: Could you post all your code so I/we can play around? Where is or() defined for example?

Comment: @Xabster attached the link to my gist

Answer (score 2):

A neat solution to this is monoid composition.

**Combining monoids**

A [monoid](https://functionaljava.ci.cloudbees.com/job/master/javadoc/fj/Monoid.html) is an associative binary operation with an identity. Your `Optional<A>` type forms a monoid for any `A`:

https://functionaljava.ci.cloudbees.com/job/master/javadoc/fj/Monoid.html#firstOptionMonoid--

In your case, the `Monoid<Optional<A>>` would be implemented using `or` as the `sum` and `Absent` as the `zero`, so `yourMonoid.sum(x, y)` should be the same as `x.or(y)`.

Now you want to combine that with another monoid--one that consists of your log. So let's say you use a simple `String` as your log. Well, `String` forms a monoid where `sum` is string concatenation and the `zero` is the empty string.

You want to combine the `String` monoid with the `firstOptionMonoid`. For that you need a tuple type. Functional Java has [a tuple type called `P2`](https://functionaljava.ci.cloudbees.com/job/master/javadoc/fj/P2.html). Here's how you combine two monoids (this should really be added to the `Monoid` class; send a pull request!):

```
import fj.*;
import static fj.P.p;
import static fj.Monoid.*;

public final <A,B> Monoid<P2<A,B>> compose(Monoid<A> a, Monoid<B> b) {
  return monoid(
    x -> y -> p(a.sum(x._1, y._1), b.sum(x._2, y._2)),
    p(a.zero, b.zero));
}
```

The composite monoid is then (in FJ):

```
Monoid<P2<Option<A>, String>> m = compose(firstOptionMonoid<A>, stringMonoid)
```

Now, you don't always want to add the log. You want it to *depend on whether a value in the `Option` is present or absent*. For that you can write a specialized method:

```
public final P2<Option<A>, String> loggingOr(
  P2<Option<A>, String> soFar,
  Option<A> additional,
  String msg) {
    return soFar._1.isDefined ?
      soFar :
      m.sum(soFar, p(additional, msg))
  }
```

I recommend looking more into monoids in general. They're a very versatile tool, and they're one of the few purely functional constructs that are actually pleasant to use in Java. If you don't mind learning in Scala, I wrote a book called [Functional Programming in Scala](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/) and [the chapter on monoids just happens to be available online](http://www.manning.com/bjarnason/FPWS_CH10.pdf) for free.

**Combining monads**

But now you are working with a composite type `P2<Option<A>, String>` rather than just `Option<A>`, and this type doesn't come with a `flatMap`. What you would really want (if Java could do that, but it can't) is to use the `Writer<String, _>` monad with a monad transformer like `OptionT`. Imagining for a moment that Java could have monad transformers, the type `P2<Option<A>, String>` would be equivalent to the type `OptionT<Writer<String, _>, A>`, where `_` indicates a partially applied type constructor (not valid Java, obviously).

The only solution in Java is to combine these monads in a first-order way:

```
import fj.data.Writer

public abstract class OptionWriter<W, A> {
  abstract Writer<W, Option<A>> writer;
  public <B> OptionWriter<W, B> flatMap(Function<A, OptionWriter<B>>) {
    ...
  }
  public static <M, T> OptionWriter<M, T> unit(t: T) {
    return Writer.unit(Option.unit(t))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a varargs approach, it would be simpler to keep track of and short to write.

```
public static <T> Optional<T> of(T... value) {
    for(int i=0;i<values.length;i++) {
        if (value[i] != null) {
            // log that value[i] was chosen
            return new Present<T>(value[i]);
        }
    }
    // log all was null
    return Absent.<T>instance();
}
```

In your example

```
String value = Optional.of(null, null, "Hello").get();
```

Comment: Yes I can do that but that would not allow me to have context specific logs. If I use optional in two different situations I need two different logs which make sense in that situation. So I thought if Logging can also be done as composition. Doing this makes Optional do logging which is orthogonal responsibility. Maybe I am wrong and am confusing things.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you have two implementations of `Optional`, `Present` and `Absent`. I suggest the introduction of another type, `LoggingAbsent` which behaves like `Absent` but logs any operation which has fall-back behavior.

The key point is to decide when to return which of these types. E.g. when converting a nullable value to an `Optional` it would be useful to return a `LoggingAbsent` instance. But when invoking `map` on an `Optional` it would be reasonable that the `LoggingAbsent` implementation logs the operation and returns a non-logging `Absent` as result so that only the first operation of a chain reports the fallback and all subsequent operations fall-back silently.

You can also support an explicit choice by providing alternative factory method for creating a logging and a non-logging `Optional`.